# Not sure why I get this error: mapboxgl.Marker is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, cordova, mapbox-gl-js

I am new to Mapboxgl and have been using it to render a map in a mobile application using Cordova. So far the map renders fine, and can zoom as expected. However, when trying to add a custom marker I get `Uncaught TypeError: mapboxgl.Marker is not a constructor`.

I have tripled check that I have installed the mapbox-gl.js library and double checked the code for typos. This code is already functional on an existing webpage, but now my goal is to try to use it in a mobile app.

I have used the demo code from the mapboxgl custom markers in CodePen and have been successful https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/.

```
function add_markers(geojson, poi, icon_name) {
// add markers to map
    geojson.features.forEach(function (marker) {
        var el = document.createElement('span');
        el.className = 'map-icon map-icon-map-pin marker '+poi;
        el.innerHTML = "<span class='tooltip "+icon(icon_name)+" marker-sub "+poi+"' title=\""+marker.properties.name+"\"></span>";
        // add marker to map
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .addTo(map);
    });
}
```

The data is mocked from this:

```
var geojson = {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
       {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -66.324462890625,
                -16.024695711685304
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Bar"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -61.2158203125,
                -15.97189158092897
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Baz"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -63.29223632812499,
                -18.28151823530889
            ]
        }
    }
]
};
```

I have also tried to just add a standard marker with no luck(same error):

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
  .setLngLat([30.5, 50.5])
  .addTo(map);
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof mapboxgl.Marker)` show?

Comment: It, unfortunately, shows `undefined`.

Comment: Are other `mapboxgl` methods working correctly?

Comment: Yes, my `mapboxgl.map` is working correctly.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that reproduces this error and make sure you're using the most recent version? (v0.38.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you must be using the old version of map-boxgl most probably v 0.20.1 ,just change the version in the link to v 0.38.0 like this:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js'>
</script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css' 
rel='stylesheet' />
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I was using NPM to install. It seems their NPM version might not be updated yet. Manually added version 0.38.0 and it's fixed.

Comment: Pleasure! select my answer as the correct one if itworked,thanks!

Comment: by the way you can specify the version when installing a package through npm like this e.g:npm install gulp@3.0.9

Comment: or you can specify the versions of your dependencies in package.json